# Is $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ ($\{ \beth_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$) a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Is $\{ \beth_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (henceforth $\beth_{\mathbb{N}}$) a set?**

I can think of two "quasi-legitimate almost-arguments" that point in different directions and therefore can't both be right.

- $ x \mapsto \beth_x$ is a 1:1 relation and $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, therefore, by replacement $\beth_{\mathbb{N}}$ is a set.
- The fact that there *can't be a set of all cardinals* seems to suggest that $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ might be a proper class rather than a set.

---

For context and motivation, I'm trying to show the consistency of a variant of [plural logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/) by building a model and invoking completeness.

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the non-negative integers.

Let $A$ be the sort of individuals. Let's further suppose that $A$ is countably infinite.

Let $P\alpha$ for any sort $\alpha$ be the sort of subsets of $\alpha$. *Unlike in ordinary plural logic, I am considering the empty subset of $\alpha$ to be an element of $P\alpha$.*

The non-logical predicates are $=$ and $\prec$. $a = b$ is a well-formed formula if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same sort. Suppose $a$ has sort $\alpha$, then $a \prec b$ is a well-formed formula if and only if $b$ has sort $P\alpha$.

So, there are countably infinitely many sorts: $A, PA, PPA, P^3A, P^4A \cdots$.

We can then construct a trivial model as follows; let's call it $M$.

The interpretation of the sort $A$ is $\mathbb{N}$.

The interpretation of the sort $P(\alpha)$ is $2^{[\alpha]}$ where $[\alpha]$ is the interpretation of $\alpha$.

The interpretation of $=$ for the sort $\alpha$ is $\{ (x, x) : x \in \alpha \}$.

The interpretation of $\prec$ where the left argument has sort $\alpha$ is:

$$ [\prec] = \{ (x, y) :  (x, y) \in \alpha \times 2^\alpha \land x \in y \} $$

**Provided I can combine $\beth_0, \beth_1, \cdots$ together, I can build a new model $M'$ that *collapses all the sorts together*. And if $\beth_{\mathbb{N}}$ exists, then $\cup \beth_{\mathbb{N}}$ exists by the axiom of union.**

Assuming the carrier of $M'$ is a set, $M'$ will have "stray equalities" that cross sort boundaries, but it is an otherwise ordinary single-sorted model and thus suffices to demonstrate the consistency of this variant of plural logic.

Comment: The indices of alephs and beths are usuallty ordinals, so that should be $\beth_{\omega}$,. not $\beth_{\mathbb{N}}$. $\mathbb{N}$ represents a richer structure than just the ordinal.

Comment: If $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ and $\beth_\omega$ are the same, then I think that answers my question affirmatively. I'm curious whether collecting the beth numbers indexed by the naturals produces a set or a proper class. $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ was supposed to be ad hoc notation defined within the question itself.

Comment: ${\beth_\omega}$ is standard notation for the _supremum_ of all the ${\beth_n}$, not for the _set_ of them. Since the supremum of a set of ordinals is just the its union, we have (in your notation) $\beth_\omega = \bigcup \beth_{\mathbb N}$

Comment: Thank you. So for the intended application of building my model, I can appeal to $\beth_\omega$ and not worry about $\beth_\mathbb{N}$. I am still curious whether $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ is a set though ... (and whether you can prove it's a set by invoking replacement or whether you have to be more careful). It sounds like $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ is a set.

Comment: I don’t understand the motivation of your second bullet point. Can you elaborate? Why the fact that the set of all cardinals doesn’t exist would imply that $\beth_{\mathbb N}$ would be a proper class rather than a set?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The second bullet point is not intended to be remotely compelling. It is just an intuitive reason why I am nervous about forming sets by collecting cardinals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The justification for the notation $\beth_\alpha$ is that the mapping $\alpha \mapsto \beth_\alpha$ can be defined by a formula of set theory, and proved to be functional (and total on the ordinals).

Therefore the axiom of replacement tells you that $\{\beth_\alpha \mid \alpha\in\omega\}$ is a set.

Your second argument:

> The fact that there *can't be a set of all cardinals* seems to suggest that $\beth_\mathbb{N}$ migh be a proper class rather than a set.

is wrong. It seems to tacitly assume that all cardinals have the form $\beth_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Even if we assume the generalized continuum hypothesis (which proposes that every cardinal is a beth number), this is not true -- the sequence of beths contiues after those numbers with $\beth_{\omega}$, $\beth_{\omega+1}$, $\beth_{\omega+2}$, and so forth with *every ordinal number* as a possible index.